# Google Chrome - No Option To Sign In After Machine Rebuild

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am running version 35.0.1916.153 of Chrome.  My machine was recently rebuilt and I am trying to sign back into chrome so my bookmarks are downloaded.

I cannot see the sign in icon any more in the Google menu bar.  Is this a known bug or has it been moved somewhere else?

The screenshot is attached which shows the contents of the menu

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: I added a screenshot of the settings tab

Comment: Some possible solutions: 1. Go to [this](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=chromiumsync&sarp=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen-GB%2Fchrome%2Fblank.html%3Fsource%3D2) link or [this](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=chromiumsync&sarp=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen-GB%2Fchromesource%3D3%26auto_close%3D1) link or [this](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=chromiumsync&sarp=1). They go to the Chrome login page. Try signing in now. 2. Disable/Remove ***all*** extensions, restart Chrome, see if the option is there now.

Comment: Note: the links in my previous comment are `.com`. ***If*** they do not work, please use the correct domain ending (eg. `.co.uk`, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this issue lays in the registry.

open regedit

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\SignInAllowed

Change the value to 1